# Python3の２の補数表現について

Tags: python, python3

Python3の２の補数表現について

16進数 list = [’35908413’,'db0bb551'] (str型)について，
最上位ビットが１であるときに負数として扱いたいと思っています。
出力結果として list = ['35908413','-24f44aaf'] となるようなPythonのプログラムの書き方を教えていただきたいです…

Comment: 「最上位ビットが1である」事を利用して、`list(map(lambda x: hex(int(x, 16) - ((int(x, 16) >> 31) << 32)), lst))` でしょうか(`list` は識別子なので `lst` に変更しています)。ただ、出力結果に `0x` が付いたままですので適当に削除して下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12202106922

Answer (score 2):

分かりやすく書くことをこころがけました。pythonは任意精度整数を扱うことができますので桁数を大きくしても同様のコードで処理することができるかと思います。

```
def fmt(s):
    n = int(s, 16)
    if n >= 0x80000000:
        return '-%x' % (0x100000000 - n)
    else:
        return s

list = ['35908413', 'db0bb551']
list = [ fmt(elem) for elem in list ]
print(list)
```

Comment: とても助かりました！ありがとうございます！